# Add data to local storage in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state, trello

I am a beginner in react.js. I am building an application like Trello, I am using a library in react.js named `react-trello`. But rather than using hard-coded data, I want to store the `data` in local Storage.

my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Board from 'react-trello'

class App extends Component {

render() {

const data = {
  lanes: [
    {
      id: 'lane1',
      title: 'Planned Tasks',
      label: '2/2',
      cards: [
        {id: 'Card1', title: 'Write Blog', description: 'Can AI make memes', label: '30 mins', draggable: true},
        {id: 'Card2', title: 'Pay Rent', description: 'Transfer via NEFT', label: '5 mins', metadata: {sha: 'be312a1'}}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'lane2',
      title: 'Completed',
      label: '0/0',
      cards: []
    }
  ]
}


return (
    <div className="App1">
    <Board style={{backgroundColor: '#ffe'}} 
           onLaneAdd={{backgroundColor: '#ffe'}}
           collapsibleLanes
           cardStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ffe'}}
           cardDraggable
           laneDraggable
           draggable
           canAddLanes
           laneStyle={{backgroundColor: '#06F491'}}
           editable
           data={data} />
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't know how can I store `data` such that I can get data even if I am `offline`. Is it possible? How can it be done?

Comment: i suggest you [app offline](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/progressive-web-apps-with-react-js-part-3-offline-support-and-network-resilience-c84db889162c)

Comment: can we store in browser cache using local-storage ?

Comment: this link help you.[app offline sample](https://medium.com/better-programming/offline-first-react-app-b79ab1a17649).so You should also consider the limitations of local storage

Comment: I also have to store the data so that next time i come my data gets rendered offline also

Comment: The library has events for handling `card addition` we can add card and store in data. Is it possible ?